# <error sending command to monitor>

Tags: ida, gdb

I'm trying to debug a backtrace created with rr so I type:

```
rr replay -s 50505 -k
```

it displays out:

```
gdb '-l' '10000' '-ex' 'set sysroot /' '-ex' 'target extended-remote 127.0.0.1:50505' target
```

Then I attach to it with ida remote debugger - i can continue, dismiss exceptions but nothing else - pressing the step over button just resumes the process.

Also rr have special set of instructions reverse-* however when i type **anything** in the gdb command line at the bottom it says:

```
<error sending command to monitor>
```

Comment: To use rr-specific commands you probably need to debug with rr...

Comment: @IgorSkochinsky It doesn't matter what commands i specify.

Comment: Does rr have any monitor commands?

Comment: @IgorSkochinsky Good question - Although I believe it does support some if IDA can cache memory and set breakpoints.

Comment: @IgorSkochinsky OK after a bit of wiresharking I see what you mean.